# why (0+0i)^{0} == (nan, nan) in c++

Tags: c++, numeric, nan, complex-numbers, exponential

take a look at the code blew:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::pow( std::complex<double>(0,0), std::complex<double>(0,0) ) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::pow( std::complex<double>(0,0), double(0) ) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

g++(4.8.1) gives an output of

```
(nan,nan)
(-nan,-nan)
```

while clang++(3.3) gives an out put of

```
(-nan,-nan)
(-nan,-nan)
```

But I am expecting (1.0, 0.0).

Can anyone give an explanation?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: It does, I don't see why he is expecting what he is expecting.

Comment: @PlasmaHH And that's why he is asking :)

Comment: `zero` to the `zero` is undefined: http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/0to0.html

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I don't think he is asking why he is expecting 1.0,0.0 ...

Comment: mathematically it should be (1, 0), but why here g++/clang++ gives (nan,nan) -- that is the question.

Answer (score 6):

According to [std::pow documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)

> **Return value**
>   base raised by power (exp or iexp).
>   Domain error occurs **if base is 0 and exp is less than or equal to ​0​.** NAN is returned in that case.
>   [...]

In your code, you have both base with 0  and exp equal to 0 since the complex number `0 + 0 *i` is still 0. So `NaN` seems expected.

By courtesy of @Fred Larson, and according to [overloaded std::pow for std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow)

> Computes complex x raised to a complex power y. The operation is defined as exp(y · log(x) ). A branch cut exists along the negative real axis.
>   **The result of pow(0, 0) is implementation-defined.**

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that citation is relevant, since `pow()` is overridden for `std::complex`. But this one is: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow Of note, "The result of pow(0, 0) is implementation-defined."

Comment: @FredLarson Which would explain visual studio giving (1,0)(1,0)?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman: Sounds like it could return anything it wants to.

Comment: before posting here, I have read the c++ standard draft n3376, but did not find this; thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

As Fred Larson correctly [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367415/why-00i0-nan-nan-in-c/17368335#comment25206117_17367574) the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow) says:

> The result of pow(0, 0) is implementation-defined.

Mathematically this makes sense since we have a contradictory situation where `N^0` should always be `1` but `0^N` should always be `0` for `N > 0`, so you should have no expectations mathematically as to the result of this either. This [Wolfram Alpha](http://community.wolframalpha.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=11131) forum posts goes into a bit more details.

The case where the imaginary portion of the complex number is not `zero` is [more complex](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/complexexp.html) situation. If the `x` in `x^y` is real then it should also be undefined but if `x` has an imaginary component then it looks like it is no longer undefined.

Comment: in Python also ? did you check ?