# Why pow(-1, 0) returns 1 instead of -1?

Tags: pow

As [google suggests](https://www.google.com/search?&q=-1%20%5E%200) -1<sup>0</sup>=-1. And as I understand pow() function in javascript, python and C should return the same result. But it's not true. Why?

Python:

```
>>> pow(-1, 0)
1
```

Comment: Don't you see what's actually being calculated? In the little calculator area, Google is actually interpreting your input as `-(1 ^ 0)`

Comment: Hey guys, that's basic math. At least learn how to use a calculator.

Comment: `0 power of any_number = 1`

Comment: `Math.pow(-1, 0)` (JavaScript) and `pow(-1.0, 0)` (C) also return 1.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Zero to the zero is ambiguous: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17368335/1708801

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a precedence thing. Google thinks [(-1)<sup>0</sup> = 1](https://www.google.com/search?&q=-1%20%5E%200#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=d750b992d784f8&q=(-1)+%5E+0&safe=off), as does Python:

```
>>> (-1)**0
1
```

[Any nonzero number raised by the exponent 0 is 1.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Arbitrary_integer_exponents)

Comment: @Dmitry: Because `pow(-1, 0) == (-1)**0`, not `-(1**0)`.

Comment: Thank you - it's an answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the parenthesis!

```
-1 ^ 0 = -(1 ^ 0) = -(1) = -1
```

because power operator has higher precedence.

But:

```
(-1)^0 = 1
```

[See on Google](https://www.google.com/search?&q=-1%20%5E%200#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=4aa6c5a77768f86e&q=%28-1%29+%5E+0)

Answer (score 1):

Anything to the power of 0 will result to 1.

Remember [BEDMASS](http://math.about.com/od/glossaryofterms/g/What-Is-Bedmas.htm).  Your google example executes Brackets (1^0) which is 1, then you executed Multiplication, negating your expression in the brackets to -1.

Answer (score 1):

**(-1<sup>0</sup>)** is the same as saying **(-1/-1)** which is **1**.

In division you substract the exponent of the denominator from the exponent of the numerator. 
For this rule to hold true all number elevated to the power of zero is 1. **5<sup>1</sup> / 5<sup>1</sup> = 5<sup>0</sup> = 1**

Comment: Why not `1/1` ? I think you wants to say `(-1 ^ 0)` ==  `( -1 ^ (1 -1))` == `-1 ^1 * -1 ^ -1` == `-1/ -1` Then Nice answer!

Comment: What I meant was that (-1^0) == **((-1^1) / (-1^1))**. Applying the rule of exponent to the second expresion give you -1^0 which is 1. Every number divided by itself equal 1 (except for zero).

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider this patterns

```
    ...
x^3  = x*x*x
x^2  = x*x
x^1  = x
x^0  = ?????
x^-1 = ?????
    ...

    ...
x^3  = 1*x*x*x
x^2  = 1*x*x
x^1  = 1*x
x^0  = 1
x^-1 = 1/x
x^-2 = 1/x/x
x^-3 = 1/x/x/x
    ...
```

A simple traditional definition of `pow` function means **how many times we multiply a number by self**.

But in more strict sense `pow` function means **how many times we multiply or divide the one by a number**.

By this reason `x^0 = 1` => `0^0 = (-1)^0 = 1` too.

In [a more general case](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) the `seed` may be any number.

```
static double Pow(double x, int pow, double seed = 1d)
{
    var value = seed;
    
    if (pow < 0)
        for (var i = 0; i > pow; i--) value /= x;
    else
        for (var i = 0; i < pow; i++) value *= x;
    
    return value;
}
```